# Centering a glyph icon within a line

Tags: css, glyphicons, glyph

I have an glyph icon with some text right next to it within a link. [Here's jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwp4hs8v/).

The bottom part of the text is aligned with the bottom part of the icon but I'm not happy with that. I want to display the icon and then align the text in its middle, not to its bottom (as a side note notice that the icon's height is 14px and the text next to it is 16px). I've tried applying margin or padding to the top of the `span` containing the icon but that moves both of them down and the alignment between them stays the same. I need to either push the icon a couple or so pixels down or the text up but without moving the other. As simple as it sounds, I'm stuck with no solution. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new class with css property `vertical-align:middle` to the `<span>` and `<a>` tag. Try the below solution, hope you help this .

**HTML**

```css
.icn {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.txt {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icn"></span>
    <span class="txt">&nbsp;text goes here</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually there are a lot of available options as values to the vertical-align that allow for different layout combinations.